# PhantomJs: inline HTML with external CSS file

Tags: phantomjs

I'm attempting to render some inline HTML which links to an external css file using the following PhantomJs script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.content = '';
page.content += '<html><head>';
page.content += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="Screen">';
page.content += '</head><body>';
page.content += '<h1>test</h1>';
page.content += '</body></html>';

page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
    console.log('::loading', requestData['url']);  // this doesn't get logged
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    console.log('::rendering');
    page.render('output.png');
    phantom.exit();
};
```

The `layout.css` file can be accessed okay with `wget`

But here's the output of phantomjs:

```
$ ./phantomjs --debug=true render_demo.js
... snip ...
2014-01-06T12:17:53 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
2014-01-06T12:17:53 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
2014-01-06T12:17:53 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100
2014-01-06T12:17:53 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 5 ( "Operation canceled" ) URL: "http://example.com/css/layout.css"
::rendering
```

There is no output `.png` file created.

Any ideas on how to ensure external CSS resources get fully loaded before rendering?
It seems to work okay when I request the same html with `page.open`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [benweet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333165/benweet) mentioned, you need to set `page.content` just once, as it will trigger a reload each time.

Because of that, in addition you will need to define your callbacks **before** actually setting the page content.

Try it like this instead:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
  console.log('::loading', requestData['url']);  // this does get logged now
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  console.log('::rendering');
  page.render('output.png');
  phantom.exit();
};

var content = '';
content += '<html><head>';
content += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen">';
content += '</head><body>';
content += '<h1>test</h1>';
content += '</body></html>';
page.content = content;
```

Comment: That was it, thanks!
I made the mistake of thinking that function assignments were always executed first in a scope (the same way as function definitions are).

Answer (score 2):

You have a setting named `localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled` controlling if local pages can access remote ressources. It appears to default to `false` so you should try to change that.

PhantomJS settings are documented [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html), so changing this setting would be done like that in your code:

```
page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;
```

just after the page creation. Since your page content is generated through scripting, I don't know if it is really considered local or remote. If this setting doesn't work, you could try setting `webSecurityEnabled` to `false`.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work. From the doc you linked to it says, "Note: The settings apply only during the initial call to the page.open function.", and I don't have a page.open call.

Comment: ditto for `webSecurityEnabled`

Comment: @EoghanM: Sorry to hear that, can't help you more, good luck!

Comment: Just one last though: try to `open` something like `about:blank` before changing `content`, this might enforce the settings?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `page.content` once. Calling the setter several times will load the page multiple times and cancel any previously unfinished async resource loading.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var content = '';
content += '<html><head>';
content += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="Screen">';
content += '</head><body>';
content += '<h1>test</h1>';
content += '</body></html>';
page.content = content;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had explored that adjustment, but it didn't make any difference: I still get the 'operation cancelled' message in the debug output.