# External CSS not taken into account on PhantomJS page

Tags: javascript, css, phantomjs

I am running Phantom on a Node server, in order to generate pages from data and then render it as pdf.

However, while the pages work and are correctly rendered as pdf and everything, I cannot get them to take into account an external CSS file.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
var phantom = require ('phantom');

phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
      var content = "";
      content += '<html><head>';
      content += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/temp.css">'; 
      content += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="./temp.css">';
      content += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="temp.css">';
      content += '</head><body>';
      content += '<div class="myClass">I am supposed to be blue</div>';
      content += '</body></html>';
      page.set('content', content);

      setTimeout(function(){ 
          page.render("MyRenderedPDF.pdf", {format: 'pdf', quality: '100'}); 
      }, 1000)});
  }, {dnodeOpts: {weak: false}});
```

(I put the three CSS references to make SURE I didn't miss my CSS due to a basic relative path syntax issue)

And the CSS:

```
.myClass { color: blue; }
```

The PDF is rendered in the folder where my server is located. My CSS is located in the same folder.

Everything displays correctly in the PDF - but the text isn't blue.

I am aware I could just force a style value into the div, but the CSS we are using are pretty extensive, and I would rather find a way to access them directly.

Any idea on what I am missing?

Comment: You need to setup an event listener I guess, for when it has finished rendering, also maybe you need to enable few things, see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950013/phantomjs-inline-html-with-external-css-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`page.set('content', content);` (or `page.content = content` in plain PhantomJS) is there to directly set the content of the page. When you do that, the domain the page is evaluated in is "about:blank". The resource "about:blank/temp.css" is simply not there.

I see two use cases here.

#### Resource is reachable from web

Either specify the full URL you want to load the resource from

```
content += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/path/temp.css">';
// OR
content += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/path/temp.css">';
```

or set the domain with [`page.setContent(html, url)`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/set-content.html):

```
page.setContent(content, "http://localhost/path/", function(){
    page.render("MyRenderedPDF.pdf", {format: 'pdf', quality: '100'}, function(){
        ph.exit();
    }); 
});
```

Don't forget the callbacks, because the phantom module is different from plain PhantomJS scripts. See [Functional Details](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#functionality-details) for more information.

#### Resource is a local file without web server

You would have to use the [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module to read the file contents and put them as an embedded stylesheet.

```
content += '<style>' + fs.readFileSync("./temp.css") + '</style';
```